# How merge tag into branch?

Tags: git

I'm building a continous integration pipeline based on a git repository.

I have 3 branch:

- master branch for the dev environment
- test branch for the test environment
- prod branch for the prod environment

Any time a branch is updated, a pipeline update my website, eg:

- when a push on master branch is made, a pipeline update https://dev.website.com
- when a push on test branch is made, a pipeline update https://test.website.com
- when a push on prod branch is made, a pipeline update https://prod.website.com

Everytime I release a new version, I update the master branch and tag the commit whit the version number:

```
# procedure for deploy on dev
git add -A
git commit -m "1.0.0"
git tag 1.0.0
git push --set-upstream origin master --tags
```

This works...

When i want to put the 1.0.0 version into test environment this is the procedure

```
# procedure for deploy on test
git fetch --tags origin
git checkout -B test
git merge 1.0.0
git push --set-upstream origin test
```

This works... but this procedure don't work on rollback, if test branch is on version 2.0.0 the snippet don't rollback the branch on version 1.0.0. If i made a:

```
git show-branch *test
```

the output show:

```
! [refs/remotes/origin/test] 2.0.0
  * [test] 2.0.0
 --
 +* [refs/remotes/origin/test] 2.0.0
```

Comment: What do you mean by *rollback?*

Comment: i mean... if i try to merge a previous tag, with the shared snippet, the branch still on the last version...

Comment: That's exactly what you should expect. A tag is a pointer to a specific commit, and does not move. Merge means *make a new commit* (except when Git can do a fast-forward instead, and you allow or require a fast-forward), and you would normally do this while being on a branch name; that moves the branch name forward. So now the branch name identifies a merge commit, and the branch contains the merge commit and *both* tagged commits.

Comment: I would not call a merge a *rollback* though. A merge is a *merge*, so call it a merge.

Comment: ok thanks... now i have understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to reset the branch and after push it

```
git reset --hard <tagname>
git push -f -u origin branch
```